# Add a not-predefined amount of input boxes to a webpage (and use that with Google App Engine)

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-app-engine

In GAE it's easy to set up an HTML page with 1 (or any other predefined number) of text input fields and then deal with the data you get. My question is how is it possible for a user to start with 1 text box, and using a button (like "Add more") to add any number of additional boxes he wants.

I'm not sure both about the HTML implementation of this (I think it'll require JS, but I'm pretty much a noob with these stuff), and the GAE implementation of this (How to write code that'll accept an arbitrary number of inputs?)

An answer to either would be very welcome; perhaps the GAE problem is not even a problem. It'll be easier for me to ponder on once I get the html/js part right.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to use text boxes? Most times when there is an undefined amount of information a listbox is a better option.

Comment: Hmm AFAIK listboxes display specific output while text boxes receive user input.

Comment: I'm sorry, you would want a combobox but i don't know if that is plausible in html. Sorry i'm in a .net mindset currently. You could essentially set up the page to have a textbox, an add button and a listbox/dropdown so that they type into the textbox, hit add, and the value appears in the list or dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer depends on what size of information you expect.  One option is an [Expando Class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/expandoclass) where you add to it as needed.

Or the easier to implement if your input is small enough you probably can get away with a [db.StringListProperty](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#StringListProperty) and use `object.append(var)` to add more fields in the post.

You will certainly need to use JavaScript to create the additional text boxes.  Then loop through the submission in the post to add the data to either option.